# Can you set some Android app's volume as relative to the device's volume?

Tags: android, volume

I want to set my app's volume as 'n%' of Android device volume at any time.
User should be able to change the value of 'n' as per his choice.
How this scenario can be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Just get the device volume first. To do that, you need to create an audio manager

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

Then you can get the system volume with this:

```
int volume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
```

Comment: I tried doing this:
`volumeSeekbar.setMax(100);
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,int progress,boolean fromUser) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
progress = (progress * (myAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)))/100;
myAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, 0);
}`

but this will change the volume of overall device music.

In my case, I want device music to be uninterrupted & retain its volume.
The app volume should be played as a percentage of device music volume.

How to achieve this?

Comment: can you help me with this @Alex?